# I want to select a region of interest manually on a matplotlib imshow function

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an image from a CT scan as a .dcm file. I used

plt.imshow(image,cmap='gray') to show it;

where "image" is a 1206x1206 array

I want to write a python code to select a circular region of interest on the CT image manually (so that I can move it around and make it smaller or bigger depending on the phantom). After selecting the region of interest I want to ask it to extract the data from the circular region I selected.

I tried using cv2 package but it only works for .jpg and .png, I think, which doesn't work for me because the data is stored in the dcm file and is plotted using matplotlib. Also, this package has the region set as a square by default, but I need it to be circular.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: your problem is about matplotlib but you didn't tag matplotlib? ftfy